# копирование двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы, строки, char

Код ниже. Он делит строку на маленькие подстрочки меньшего размера (чанки фиксированной величины, для примера 10), получается двумерный массив, где основной массив - количество чанков, а подмассив - количество символов в чанке (10). Нужно переопределить метод subSequence, получающий диапазон строки, которую нужно выдернуть из основного двумерного массива. Проблема в том, что никак не получается скопировать определенные значения из основного массива в подмассив, что я создаю в этом методе (т.е. если диапазон начался в одном чанке, а заканчивается в другом, нужно выдернуть количественное значение в этом чанке). 
Я задал смещение, которое находится между чанками, всего три чанка по 25, 84 элемента, мне нужны элементы с 26 по 56. Т.е начало в первом чанке, конец во втором - > нужный диапазон сложно задать, оперируя целыми числами.

```
package edu.technopolis;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CustomString implements CharSequence {
private char [][] chars;
private String inputS;
private final int DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH = 10;
private int offset;
private int tmpLength;
private int count;

private CustomString( char[][] chars) {
   this.chars = chars;
}

@Override
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0 || end < 0 || end > inputS.length() || start > end) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("out of border");
    }
    char [][] chars;
    this.offset = start; // задаем смещение
    this.count = end - start; // задаем количество
    int chunk_start = start / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH;
    int chunk_end = end / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH + 1;

    if(count < DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH){
         chars = new char[(count / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH) + 1][count];
    }
    else {
        chars = new char[(count / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH)][count]; // выделяем память под кусок и под количество сабстринтов
        for (int i = 0; i < (count / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH); i++) { // идем циклом от 0 до целого количества, необходимого нам чтобы заполнить первый массив
            for (int j = 0, k = offset; j < count; j++, k++) { // идем от нуля до количества элементов, ставим k в offset
                chars[i][j] = this.chars[][k]; // что писать тут? 
            }
        }
    }
    return new CustomString(chars);
}
public CustomString(String inputS) {
    this.offset = 0;
    this.count = 0;
    this.inputS = inputS;
    this.tmpLength = this.inputS.length();
    if(this.inputS.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if(inputS.length() % DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH == 0) {
        this.chars = new char[this.inputS.length() / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH][this.inputS.length()];
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.inputS.length()/DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH; i++){
            for(int indexInputS = 0; indexInputS < DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH;indexInputS++,j++){
                this.chars[i][j] = this.inputS.charAt(indexInputS);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(inputS.length() % DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH != 0) {
        this.chars = new char[(this.inputS.length() / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH) + 1][]; //выделил ровно столько, сколько нужно
        for(int i = 0; i < this.inputS.length() / DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH; i++){ //
            this.chars[i] = new char[DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH]; // выделил чанку память
        }
        this.chars[this.inputS.length()/DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH] = new char[this.inputS.length() % DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH]; //выделил ровно столько, сколько нужно сабстрингу
        for(int i = 0; i < this.inputS.length(); i++){
            this.chars[i/DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH][i%DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH] = this.inputS.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public int length() {
    return this.inputS.length();
}

@Override
public char charAt(int index) {
   if ((index < 0) || (index >= inputS.length())) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
   }
   return this.chars[index/DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH][index%DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH];
}




@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < tmpLength; i++ ){
        tmp.append(this.chars[i/DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH][i%DEFAULT_CHUNK_LENGTH]);
    }
    return tmp.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: upd - Я, например, задал смещение которое находится между чанками , Т.е это не целое число, допустим, всего три чанка по 25, 84 элемента, мне нужны элементы с 26 по 56 . Т.е начало в первом чанке, конец во втором - > нужный диапазон сложно задать, оперируя целыми числами.

Comment: не используйте столько вводных слов. это же не сочинение, а конкретный вопрос.